# C# library for fuzzy string comparisons

Tags: software-development, library

I've recently tried to make use of SQL SoundEx to implement a smart search function an ASP.NET MVC web application, but haven't been able to get it to work as I desire. Is there a C# library that provides fuzzy string comparisons?

Comment: Do you care about license?

Answer (score 2):

The [FuzzyString](https://github.com/kdjones/fuzzystring) library makes use of various algorithms for approximate string comparisons. It allows you to specify any one or more of the algorithms to use for each comparison. Following is a list of all available algorithms:

- Hamming Distance
- Jaccard Distance
- Jaro Distance
- Jaro-Winkler Distance
- Levenshtein Distance
- Longest Common Subsequence
- Longest Common Substring
- Overlap Coefficient
- Ratcliff-Obershelp Similarity
- Sorensen-Dice Distance
- Tanimoto Coefficient